# How to add separate and distinct COLUMN GROUPS to my SSRS report that are OUTSIDE of the current column group

Tags: reporting-services

Currently I have query that displays the output in my SSRS report as:
[image]

I need my SSRS report to display as such:
[image]

My problem is I don't know how to add the 4 additional column groups, Incurred Loss and it's total column, as well as the Loss Ratio with LAE column and its total into this report.  It's not very intuitive.  Hope that makes sense.  Here is what my SSRS report looks like in the DESIGN window of SSRS:
[image: 4]

Comment: hard to see from your report design how it is grouped.. my guess is.. you have a tablix.. but the looks of what you want.. you need a matrix.. have the same group on your rows and other columns as column groups

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harry, this is a matrix report that I have shown above. Appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this easily with the current layout of your dataset (I'm assuming your dataset looks pretty much like the first image?).

Ideally your dataset should look something like this.

```
AgentOwnerName  AgencyName  LocationName   AgentNo   Measure      Period Amount
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Earned Prem  16-17   35700
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Earned Prem  17-18   50680
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Earned Prem  18-19   37310
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Earned Prem  19-20   29150
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Inc. Loss    16-17   37220
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Inc. Loss    17-18   16840
....
Acme Ins.       Acme Ins.   Insurance      23951     Loss Ratio   16-17    1.13
...
```

Once your data is in this format, you can add two column groups, the parent group will be by `Measure` and the child group will be by `Period`

Comment: Alan, thanks for taking time to reply. In your example I would need a Measure column with the types of EP, Inc Loss and Loss Ratio.  So I would need to pivot my SQL dataset and then I should be able to get what I characterized above "I need my SSRS report to be displayed as such".  I'll try that. Again, thanks.

Comment: actually you need to UNPIVOT it assuming that the dataset originally looked like the 1st image. Once you have the flat table in the dataset it will be simple to pivot it in a matrix as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I actually received a response from Amelia in the MSDN forum and what she suggested was to DROP the Total column from my matrix above and then do a SUM(EP) and then right-click and select ADD GROUP and then adjacent right which I did for the Incurred Loss and Loss Ratio columns.  I then added a TOTAL column for each Earned Premium, Incurred Loss and Loss Ratio column to get the 3 separate column groups.  It worked brilliantly.  I didn't have to change the result set from my stored procedure at all.  I hope this helps someone else.  Thanks.